# How to invert CGContextClip()

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I want to invert the CGContextClip()
so with this code:

```
    let startPoint: CGFloat = CGFloat(degreesToRadians(270))
    let endPoint: CGFloat = CGFloat(degreesToRadians(0))

    var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, CGFloat(self.frame.size.width / 2.0), CGFloat(self.frame.size.height / 2.0), 155, startPoint, endPoint, false)
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, CGFloat(self.frame.size.width / 2.0), CGFloat(self.frame.size.height / 2.0), 84, endPoint, startPoint, true)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path)

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGPathGetBoundingBox(path), image.CGImage)
    CGContextFillPath(ctx)
    CGContextClosePath(ctx)
    CGContextClip(ctx)
```

I'm getting this  : 
[image]

Is it posible to invert clipping area to get image inside my line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This code isn't clipping anything

It's just filling your path with black. You need to call `CGContextClip` *before* you draw your image. That in itself should achieve your desired effect (having the image masked *within* the arc area).

Also, `CGContextClosePath` should be called *before* adding your path to the context. And if you're just masking, you shouldn't need to call `CGContextFillPath`.

Something like this should achieve what you want:

```
let startPoint = -CGFloat(M_PI)*0.5
let endPoint = CGFloat(0)

let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, frame.size.width / 2.0, frame.size.height / 2.0, 155, startPoint, endPoint, false)
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, frame.size.width / 2.0, frame.size.height / 2.0, 84, endPoint, startPoint, true)
CGContextClosePath(ctx)
CGContextAddPath(ctx, path)
CGContextClip(ctx)

CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGPathGetBoundingBox(path), image.CGImage)
```

[image]

If you still need the inverse, [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36604132/2976878) has got you covered.

---

#### Side Node

You (most of the time) don't need to explicitly supply type information when defining a variable. Let Swift infer it. Therefore, you can replace lines like this:

```
var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
```

with this:

```
var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use specify a different fill mode (even-odd) and use an outer path along with your main (inner) path which should give you what you're looking for. Here's some additional details that might help: [Drawing Hollow circle in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856823/drawing-hollow-circle-in-iphone)